# Gradle - build subprojects subprojects

Tags: gradle

Assume I have a Gradle project that looks like

```
RootProject
  |-- SubProject1
  |   |- SubProject1A
  |   |  `- build.gradle
  |   `- SubProject1B
  |      `- build.gradle
  |-- SubProject2
  |    |- SubProject2A
  |    |  `- build.gradle
  |    `- SubProject2B
  |       `- build.gradle
  |- gradle.build
  `- settings.gradle
```

Is it possible to build a subprojects all subprojects? I want to run

```
gradle :SubProject1:build
```

But it doesn't build the subprojects `SubProject1A` and `SubProject1A`

My `settings.gradle` looks like

```
include ":SubProject1:SubProject1A"
include ":SubProject1:SubProject1B"
include ":SubProject2:SubProject2A"
include ":SubProject2:SubProject2A"
```

How can I build a subprojects all subprojects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I believe you also need a `build.gradle` in SubProject1 and SubProject2

Edit:

I found the solution.

Create a `build.gradle` in SubProject1 and SubProject2 and add a task dependency to SubProject1A and SubProject1B etc like this:

```
build.dependsOn ':SubProject1:SubProject1A:build', ':SubProject1:SubProject1B:build'
```

You can then run `:SubProject1:build` and it will also execute `:SubProject1:SubProject1A:build` and `:SubProject1:SubProject1B:build`

Comment: I added an empty `build.gradle` to SubProject1 and SubProject2 but Gradle will still not build `SubProject1A` and `SubProject1A` when I invoke the command `gradle :SubProject1:build`. Running Gradle 2.7